# using IFS to delimit by comma, ends after first arg read

Tags: bash, unix

I have a var like:

```
TOPICS=A,B,C,D
```

And a bash script to read them like:

```
ssh user@host2 <<EOF
 IFS=$','
 for word in $TOPICS; do
  $PATH_TO_SCRIPT \$word
 done
exit
EOF
```

But the script at $PATH is only being called for TOPIC 'A' and then the loops exits, any idea what is going on?

Comment: Are you really using `$PATH` as a variable in your script? That's normally the list of directories searched for executables.

Comment: no, thats not the actual var name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh user@host2 <<EOF
 IFS=$','
 RTOPICS='$TOPICS'
 for word in \$RTOPICS; do
  $PATH_TO_SCRIPT \$word
 done
exit
EOF
```

You need to do the variable expansion on the remote system, so that IFS will be used to split the words.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the variable on your local machine (that's what I assume from the question), do the expansion on the local machine:

```
TOPICS=A,B,C,D
IFS=, read -ra topic_words <<< "$TOPICS"

ssh user@host2 <<EOF
 for word in ${topic_words[*]}; do
  $PATH_TO_SCRIPT \$word
 done
exit
EOF
```

This will break if there is whitespace in $TOPICS. If that's the case, then:

```
TOPICS="A a,B b,C c,D d"

ssh user@host2 <<EOF
 IFS=, read -ra topic_words <<< "$TOPICS"
 for word in "\${topic_words[@]}"; do
  $PATH_TO_SCRIPT "\$word"
 done
exit
EOF
```

I'm assuming your login shell on the remote end is bash.